# How can i use python to read output of linux program (top)

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, system

after struggling trying to figure out how to use python to save the output of the "top" linux command to a variable and then using grep to get a line, I couldn't make it.

I have read in the python documentation about the use of the subprocess module but this doesn't seem to work properly. That is because when you run the top command in linux, you get an alive windows that is refreshing continuously. "Top" is not the same as "ls" or "cp".

So my question is this:
How can i use python to get system statistics like CPU percentages etc? (preferebly using the top command, but it would be okay if i would use another command or if i were to read the statistics from a file)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (It is, by the way, very possible to get the output from top through a pipe (stdin) but you will get continuous updates, so you need to read for a while, then stop.)

Comment: If you run 'top -n 1' it will display the current processes without refreshing. For the statistics of a file, use os.stat().

Comment: You can run top in batch mode -b and parse the output. Or you can read about the /proc filesystem.

Comment: or u can use this package to parse for you https://github.com/sweetim/linux-top-parser

Answer (score 3):

If getting process information in Python, @LeGre is correct, you should use the [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) library

However, to answer the more general quesion of *"How can i use python to read output of linux program"*, I will use *top* as an example. This methodology could be used for any fixed width text source.

Note: This example should work on Linux 5.3 (Ubuntu 18.04). Other distributions may have different column offsets or columns headings. Adjust as required.

```
import subprocess, sys, re
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

def main(argv):
    output = subprocess.check_output(['top', "-bn1", "-o", "%MEM"])

    match = re.match(r'^[\w\W]*?\n( +PID.*COMMAND)\n([\w\W]*)', output.decode())

    header = match[1]
    data = match[2]

    df = pd.read_fwf( StringIO(data)
        , colspecs = [(0,5), (6,16), (16,18), (19,22), (23,30), (31,37), (38,44), (45,46), (47,52), (53,57), (58,67), (68,999) ]
        , names    = ['PID', 'USER',    'PR',    'NI',  'VIRT',   'RES',   'SHR',     'S',  '%CPU',  '%MEM', 'TIME+', 'COMMAND']
    )

    print(df.to_dict(orient='index'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `-b` and `-n` to get output from top:

```
-b  :Batch-mode operation
    Starts top in Batch mode, which could be useful for sending output
    from top to other programs or to a file.  In this mode, top will
    not accept input and runs until the iterations limit you've set
    with the `-n' command-line option or until killed.

-n  :Number-of-iterations limit as:  -n number
    Specifies the maximum number of iterations, or frames, top should
    produce before ending.
```

For example:

```
$ top -b -n 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`top` by default uses ncurses so getting output from it will be tricky.

Python has a package called [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil). You should use that instead.

If you really want to use `top` you'll need to pass the `-b` option (batch mode)

From the manpage

> In this mode, `top` will not accept input and runs until the iterations limit you've set with the `-n` command-line option or until killed.

So you can try something like this

`>>> output = subprocess.check_output(['top', '-b', '-n1'])`

Answer (score 0):

`samples` option of `top` command allows sampling n-times. So, following command runs only one time and breaks after that:

```
top -l 1
```