# How do I join rows in pandas dataframe as new line in same row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
time text
01.01.1970 abc
01.01.1970 cde
01.01.1970 fgh
01.01.1980 abc
01.01.1980 xyz
```

I would like to join the rows of column `text` based on the entry for `time`. A new row should start in a new line.

The new dataframe should look like this:

```
time text
01.01.1970 abc
           cde
           fgh
01.01.1980 abc
           xyz
```

I tried this code:

```
out = (df.groupby('time', as_index=False)
       ['text'].agg(lambda x: '\n'.join(x.dropna())))
```

But first: join by \n is not want I want. And secondly, the text column is just `text\ntime`. How can I modify my code or should I use another approach?

My question is related to this question:
[How can i use python to read output of linux program (top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460580/how-can-i-use-python-to-read-output-of-linux-program-top)

Comment: Why do you want to do that? is there a specific reason?

Comment: if joining by '\n' is not what you want, what do you want? either you have multiple values in a index or only one separated by \n or in a list.

Comment: Yes, what I want to do is to get one dataframe for each timestamp. After having this dataframes for each index I want to use the `text`column and convert it to a string and then use regex and the `.read_fwf`function to read my data in a special format.

Comment: @ZiurOlpa: I want to have it in a real new line in order to be able to use a special regex to match certain patterns in my data.

Comment: My question is related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460580/how-can-i-use-python-to-read-output-of-linux-program-top. I want to read the output of several sequences of the top command to a pandas dataframe.

Comment: `\n` is a real newline. Is that the confusion?

Comment: Ok, thank you! But there is still the problem remaining that text is not abc\ndef\nfgh but text\ntime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code (updated as per OP comment below), this code will preserve order:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['01.01.1970','01.01.1970','01.01.1970','01.01.1980','01.01.1980'],'text':['cde','abc','fgh','abc','xyx']})


new_df = df.groupby(['time','text'], sort=False).agg({'text':'count'}).iloc[:,:-1]
new_df
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But it looks like the lines of the new dataframe is ordered alphabetically now. That is not what it is supposed to look like...

Comment: I have updated the code, this will preserve order of original data

Comment: A much shorter way to get the same output is just `df.set_index(['time', 'text'])`